# Asynchronous Javascript Request Issue (Node, request-promise module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am building an application and having an issue with making a request from the client, sending it to my server, having the server make the API call and then send the result back to the client. I am using Node and the Request-Promise module.

Here is the client side code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var artistSearch = () => {
        const q = $('.artistName').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/request",
            data: {artist: q},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log('data: ', data)
        })
    };

    $(".artistSearch").submit( () => {
        artistSearch();
    });
});
```

This successfully makes a request to the server:

```
app.post('/request', (req, res) => {
    const artist = req.body.artist;
    const searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?     q="+artist+"&type=artist";
    var targetObj;

    var options = {
        uri: searchURL
    };

    rp(options)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('complete');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error') 
        });
```

});

Which ultimately successfully grabs the data from the API call, but never sends it back to the client! If I do res.send() outside of my .then promise, I can receive data on the client end.

Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't get _any_ logs?

Comment: This is a typo bug lol. You're sending the string `'data'` instead of the variable `data` in your code.

Comment: That was for testing purposes - even still, no data comes through.

Comment: Are you getting any errors logged in the console? Is your code hitting the first `.then(function(data){`

Comment: No errors, only my API object and my 'complete' string.

Comment: My code is hitting the first .then - but seemingly isn't being sent to my client. Or perhaps my AJAX request is incorrect?

Comment: Hm...Maybe add fail(function(err)) to Ajax request and see what you got there.

Comment: Have you tried sending a status code (e.g. 200)? `res.status(200).send(data);`...

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk .fail provided a result, so my Ajax call is failing.

Comment: Well..check your PHP API...from what i see...you just need to make API call from express to your PHP API -> this will return result from DB..and then you send response to user.. User will not know what happen and your code on front-end will get data.. Just make sure that your PHP API are able to receive calls from all. Also make sure you have some secret key or something like this to prevent other people to use it.

Comment: I am not using a PHP API.

Comment: Can you able to log the response inside the promise?

Comment: Put a  ` .error(function(err) { console.log('err: ', err) })` on your ajax call and open check at the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what is happening with this request.

Comment: What exactly does "*seemingly isn't being sent to my client*" mean? What does the network panel in the browser devtools say?

Comment: Since you're running on localhost, are you sure there's no SOP issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a case of including `event.preventDefault();` in the submit handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var options = {
    uri: searchURL,
    simple: false,
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        res.status(200).send(data).end();
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('complete');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error') 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the client did receive data, but the connection didn't terminate correctly as it thinks there are more data.  This is because you didn't specify the header and the module http couldn't figure out the content-length.

```
rp(options)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // res.send(data);

        // assume data is JSON.  
        res.setHeader (200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                             'Content-Length':data.byteLength});
        res.end(data);  //Send data immediately.
    })
```

...

If data is a string, you will need to use data.length instead.  In fact, if data is a string, then by default the header is `{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length':data.length}`